# Automatically generate constraints for trajectory optimization

Tags: matlab, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming, discrete-optimization

This is a follow up to my previous post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34652/solving-a-parameter-estimation-problem-using-trajectory-optimization)

I'm interested in performing trajectory optimization from the problem mentioned in abov link.

I want to supply the following as dynamical constraints to  MATLAB's `fmincon`.

$$ \frac{d \phi}{dt}  = -M^TDM\phi   + W \hspace{1cm}(1)$$

$\phi$ is a vector with variables [ A B C D E F].

I've been referring to this [article](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/16M1062569) that illustrates how trapezoidal collocation is done

For example, if $\phi$ is a scalar

$$\dot\phi = f \hspace{1cm} (2)$$

integrating the above from time $t_k$ to $t_{k+1}$ and approximating using trapezoidal quadrature gives,

$$ \phi_{k+1} = \phi_k + \frac{1}{2}h_k(f_{k+1} + f_k) \hspace{1cm} (3)$$

This will translate into a set of non-linear equality constraints ([ref](http://sam.pfrommer.us/tutorial-direct-collocation-trajectory-optimization-with-matlab)) for k = 0 to N-1.

I would like to know how to generate these constraints automatically. Is it possible to generate these constraints automatically and pass it as a handle to `fmincon`. Because it is possible to manually write for a single variable but for multivariable it gets complex.

I also looked at a repository available [here](https://github.com/MatthewPeterKelly/OptimTraj) that can be used in MATLAB. However, I am not sure if this can be used to generate constraints.

Also, I would like to understand how equation (3) should actually be written as an equality constraint.
Should one solve the ode system in (1) and use the values of $\phi$ at the collocation points to evaluate the RHS of equation (3)? What happens to RHS?

Any suggestions/explanations for the above questions will be really useful.

EDIT:
I tried following the example code given [here](http://sam.pfrommer.us/tutorial-direct-collocation-trajectory-optimization-with-matlab?unapproved=1215&moderation-hash=7958ecf27bc52ec8cb6f28171fcf69d0#comment-1215) to understand how ceq (equality constraint) has to be implemented

For example, in the code provided in the above link

```
function [ c, ceq ] = double_integrator_constraints( x )
```

is given.

Could someone explain how the input argument, x, is computed?
Also, I don't understand how `ydesiredend` has to be mentioned in equality constraints.

In my problem, only the initial conditions are defined for the dynamical constraints and the terminal conditions are not available. In that case , I am not sure how the equality constraints have to be defined.

EDIT2: 
Update: I could solve this problem using fminunc and lsqnonlin.

```
Dhat0 = %input vector 
% fun   = @objfun;
% [Dhat,fval] = fminunc(fun, Dhat0)

%% lsqnonlin
Dhat = lsqnonlin(@(Dhat) objfun(Dhat),Dhat0)


function f = objfun(Dhat)

%% Integrator settings
tspan = %tspan 
options = odeset('abstol', 1e-10, 'reltol', 1e-9);

%% generate exact solution
    phi0 = % initial condition vector
    [t, phi]  = ode15s(@(t,phi) exact(t,phi), tspan , phi0 ,options);


%% generate approximate solution

    [t, phi_tilde]  = ode15s(@(t,phi_tilde) approx(t,phi_tilde, Dhat), tspan , phi0 ,options);


%% objective function for fminunc
    % diff = (phi - phi_tilde).*(phi - phi_tilde);
    % f = sum(diff, 'all')

%% objective function for lsqnonlin
    f  = phi - phi_tilde
end
```

I am still interested in understanding how the constrained optimization problem can be solved. I'm trying to set up the problem this way.

I would like to understand how `noncol` should be called from fmincon.

```
nonlcon = @defects;
Dhat= fmincon(@objfun,Dhat0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon)
```

For my system,
A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub = []

But, I am not sure from where to pass these arguments for  `defects(dt,x,f)`.

```
function [c ceq] = defects(dt,x,f)
    % ref: https://github.com/MatthewPeterKelly/OptimTraj
    % This function computes the defects that are used to enforce the
    % continuous dynamics of the system along the trajectory.
    %
    % INPUTS:
    %   dt = time step (scalar)
    %   x = [nState, nTime] = state at each grid-point along the trajectory
    %   f = [nState, nTime] = dynamics of the state along the trajectory
    %
    % OUTPUTS:
    %   defects = [nState, nTime-1] = error in dynamics along the trajectory
    %   defectsGrad = [nState, nTime-1, nDecVars] = gradient of defects


nTime = size(x,2);

idxLow = 1:(nTime-1);
idxUpp = 2:nTime;

xLow = x(:,idxLow);
xUpp = x(:,idxUpp);

fLow = f(:,idxLow);
fUpp = f(:,idxUpp);

% This is the key line:  (Trapazoid Rule)
defects = xUpp-xLow - 0.5*dt*(fLow+fUpp);
ceq = reshape(defects,numel(defects),1);
c = [];
end
end
```

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Comment: What you have is what's called an "optimal control problem". You might want to take a look at books and articles on the subject. It is not efficient to use a standard optimization method such as `fmincon` for these kinds of problems, but there are very efficient optimal control algorithms.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you. I've been referring to chapters 3 and 4 of the book by Betts and articles by Kelly. to start with I have a simple system with 6 variables, so I'd prefer to solve it using fmincon to understand how the problem has to be set up. I'll definitely read more on other efficient algorithms. The problem now is, I am unsure about how the constraints have to be set up for solving in fmincon.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The other doubt that I have is, the control variables in my system i.e $\hat{D}$ are not functions of time. I'd like to understand if this can still be solved as an optimal control problem.

Comment: If you are imposing all these constraints, do you even expect there to be a solution in the case with noise? You are basically trying to exactly fit random noise with 6 degrees of freedom

Comment: @whpowell96 I am not sure if I can find a solution with all these constraints. But I really want to try if imposing the condition works when noise term is set to zero. The problem ow is, I don't know how to formulate the equality constraints (in the code) using equation(1) when W=0. I understand I have to use the trapezoidal rule, but I am stuck as to how this should be implemented in the code.

Comment: Any suggestions?